# Show/hide columns based on input value

Tags: excel, vba

I have one input sheet "Sheet I", Input cell: C3, the input value will be integer, such as 1, 2, 3... .
The output sheets are "Out 1", "Out 2", "Out 3", ..."Out 10". Some output sheets contain the content from A2 to G36, while others contain the information from A2 to H36 or T36. Ideally, I would like to see columns (starting from column C) conditionally based on the value in $C$3 in sheet I. Here is the logic:

- If Input Value = 1, show Column A, Column B and Column C
- If Input Value = 2, show Column A, Column B and Column D
- If Input Value = 6, show Column A, Column B and Column H
- .....

Right now I have this VBA, but the input value in this code is set static number. Can anyone advise how should I change the code in order to make it work?

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetCalculate(ByVal Sh As Object)
Dim ShArray
Dim i
Dim MyRange, c As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ShArray = Array("Out 1", "Out 2", "Out 3", "Out 4", "Out 5",.. "Out 10")
For i = LBound(ShArray) To UBound(ShArray)
    Set MyRange = Sheets(ShArray(i)).Range("A:T")
    For Each c In MyRange
        Sheets(ShArray(i)).Rows(c.Column).Hidden = c.Value = "??"
    Next c
Next i
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

No quite sure if this is what you are looking for but you should try this.

```
If InputValue = 1 then
Sheets(ShArray(i)).Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = false
elseif InputValue = 2 then 
'...
elseif InputValue = 3 then 

End if
```